# What is Equipotent relation?

Tags: real-analysis

In Royden's book Real Analysis, page 13, he writes that "We call two sets A and b equipotent provided there is a one-to-one mapping $f$ from A onto B Equipotence defines a equivalence relation among sets, that is, it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive." He then uses equipotence to $\mathbb{N}$ define countably infinite.

I find out another definition of countably infinite using injection which is a one-to-one and left-total relation, not necessarily onto. But if it's not onto, how can the equipotence be symmetric?

When proving that the Cartesian product $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinite, he defines a mapping $g$ by $g(m,n)=(m+n)^2+n$. This mapping from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is one-to-one but not onto.

Comment: Did you prove that it is not onto?

Comment: @JulianRachman It isn't onto. There are no $a$ and $b$ such that $g(a,b)=3$. It isn't symmetric, $g(1,2)=11$ but $g(2,1)=10$.

Comment: Leave alone the second definition for a second. My argument is that if equipotent relation is symmetric he then needs to prove not only that **NxN** is equipotent to **N**, which he did, but also that **N** is equipotent to **NxN**. Then we need a one-to-one and left-total mapping _f_  from **N** to **NxN**. In other words, he needs a bijective mapping, not just a injective mapping.

Comment: @casablancahp Are you familiar with the way that it is proved that the rational numbers are countable? You can apply the same trick to show that $N\times N$ is countable.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Here's a useful link which helps me understand the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable

Answer (score 1):

The function isn't onto since there is no $a$, $b$ such that $g(a,b)=3$. You can see this by considering a few cases: $g(0,1)=2$, $g(1,0)=1$, $g(0,0)=0$, and $g(1,1)=5$.

However, if $g(a,b)$ is unique in $\Bbb N$ then it's possible to define a bijective mapping $f$ from the range of $g$ to $\Bbb N$ such that $f \circ g$ is onto. (I don't know whether $g(a,b)$ actually is unique in $\Bbb N$.)

Regardless of whether this function $g$ "works" or not, we can make a bijective map from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ using the same trick as the one for proving that the rational numbers are countable. The general result is that the cross-product of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: As you said, there are no such _a_ and _b_ that _g(a,b)=3_. Then there's no bijective mapping from **NxN** to **N**.  The proof is fine if it's based on the second definition. But Royden's definition of countably infinite using equipotence confuses me.Especially the symmetric relation he mentioned.

Comment: To answer your question, _g(a,b)_ is unique (one-to-one) in **N** cause _m=a_ and _n=b_ if _g(m,n)=g(a,b)_. _|m+n+a+b||m+n-a-b|=|b-n|_. So _b=n_ otherwise the natural number _m+n+a+b_both divides and greater than the natural number |b-n|. It's the proof in Royden's book.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where Royden gives the definition of countably infinite using injection. If this is in reference to Theorem 3 on page 13, I think it only says "A subset of a countable set is countable."

Consider $A \subseteq B$, with B a countable set.

In the proof he discusses two cases, one where B is finite, and the other when B is countably infinite.

In the countably infinite case, he gives a selection process that forms a one-to-one correspondence between ℕ and A. If A is not finite, we can show that not only is A countable (finite or countably infinite), it is countably infinite.

Thus, as long as B is countably infinite, A a subset of B and A not finite, we can use the selection process he mentions to create a bijection between ℕ and A.

When proving that the Cartesian product ℕ×ℕ is countably infinite, he creates an injection from ℕ×ℕ to ℕ. Thus there is a bijection from ℕ×ℕ to a subset of ℕ. Since ℕ is countably infinite, we can use the selection process mentioned above to create a bijection from this subset of ℕ to ℕ.