# $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

$$\mathbb N\times\mathbb N \text{ is countable}.$$

Is there any way to prove it using induction? without fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Comment: You mean the Cartesian product?

Comment: yes $$\Bbb N × \Bbb N$$

Comment: Using induction...? I am not quite sure I understand. Do you want an explicit bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yes, for example: "The set is countable because there are proofs that show that, and if it wasn't countable then they wouldn't work. The other proofs work, and therefore the set is countable. QED"

Comment: yea proving its a bijection using induction

Comment: @AsafKaragila You should reference where this technique comes from: http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=1099 :)

Comment: This is a duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/the-cartesian-product-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-is-countable

Comment: Perhaps if you have an bijection N-->N , that would be the initial step for induction, then you can extend to N-->NxN ?   ( and then NxNxN, etc, that would be novel)

Comment: @user247608: Your induction idea works in showing that $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\times \cdot \times \mathbb{N}$ ($n$ of them) is countable. The induction step from $n=k$ to $n=k+1$, where $k\ge 2$, is easy. Unfortunately, going from $1$ to $2$ takes some work.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to think about that - of course, this is not the easy or obvious way, but it could be interesting if I have time to think about it.    As far as I know, induction is generally used on finite sets, so this is a very non-obvious problem to consider!

Comment: how about $f: N \times N -> N$ given by f((m,n))= m + $\sum_{i=0}^{m+n-2} i$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $N$ means $\Bbb N$ and $*$ means Cartesian product. So you are actually requesting a proof that $\Bbb N^2$ is countable.

There is indeed no need for an appeal to induction, since we already have many very apparent ways to enumerate them all, like $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2),(3,0),(2,1),(1,2),(0,3),\cdots$ in which every element appears exactly once.

PS: then comes the part where induction comes into play :). Starting from here, you should be able to show that for any $p\in\Bbb N^+$, $\Bbb N^p$ is countable, and, in the same spirit, that the Cartesian product of a *finite* collection of countable sets is again countable.