# Is the set of terms of a sequence countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

According to [Rosen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383090), an infinite set A is countable if $|A|= |\mathbb{Z}^+|$ which in turn can be established by finding a bijection from A to $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Also, a sequence is defined as a function from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ (or $\{0\} \cup \mathbb{Z}^+$) to some set.

With the above, a sequence is certainly enumerable. However, it need not be a bijection, e.g. Fibonacci(1) = Fibonacci(2) = 1.

This implies that not every sequence is countable which seems counterintuitive. Are there any results in this regard? Is there a mistake in the reasoning above?

Comment: Is the sequence $1,1,1,...$ countable?

Comment: I suppose you mean the values taken by the sequence, that is, given a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ (or $\mathbb Z^+$) then you're asking if the set $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is countable, right?

Comment: "This implies that not every sequence is countable" ... um, i'm not following.  Why does it imply that?  A function from a countable set must be countable whether it is a bijection or not.

Comment: @amrsa Yes, that is the question.

Comment: @Yanko The set of terms is {1} which is finite, thus countable.

Comment: In that case every sequence is countable.

Answer (score 2):

Every sequence has a countable  or a finite set of values.

Besides, you are mixing two ideas : a sequence $(u_n)_n$ is a function $n\mapsto u_n\in F$ ($F$ being any possible set)  and almost never a bijection, but the set of all its values are finite or countable.

Comment: Yes, I made a more precise statement.

Answer (score 2):

"However, it need not be a bijection"

No, it doesn't.

"This implies that not every sequence is countable"

Why do you say that?

$f: \mathbb Z^+ \to B$.  If $f$ is not surjective then there are points of $B$ that are not in the image.  Those to not matter.  We can restrict ourselves to $f: \mathbb Z^+ \to Im(B)$.

This *must* be surjective.

It doesn't need to be injective however and your Fibinocci example shows.

But... so what?  Than means $|Im(B)| \le |\mathbb Z^+|$.

Hence it *MUST* be countable (or countably finite).

Anyway, as the terms of a sequence, as opposed to a set, need not be distinct it is possible, indeed common, for a sequence to have a finite number of distinct terms infinitely repeated.

Comment: A bijection is invertible. Consider the bijection from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to the terms of the Fibonacci sequence. If the set of terms of the Fibonacci sequence is countably infinite, then, as per definition, such a bijection must exist. Let us call it $f$. What is $f^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: @wsaleem The bijection need not be given by the sequence itself ...

Comment: Agreed. But no matter the function, we will have 2 distinct elements in the domain ($\mathbb{Z}^+$) mapping to the element, 1, in the co-domain. This function is not injective and therefore not a bijection. Thus, it seems that no bijection exists from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to the set of terms of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Wsaleem.  I honestly fail to see your point.

Comment: f (1)=13,f(2)=8;f (3)=1;f (4)=21;f (5)=3 etc.  Is a bijection.

Comment: A sequence may list a value many times that the range set itself is an *unordered* set of distinct values.  Take $c_n = n^2* \frac 16 - \lfloor n^2* \frac 16 \rfloor =\{\frac 16, \frac 23, \frac 12, \frac 23, \frac 16, 0, \frac 16, etc\}$.  This is a map from $\mathbb N\to\{0,\frac 16,\frac 23,\frac 12\}$ a finite set.  This is clearly not a bijection.  $c^{-1}(\frac 23) = \{2,4,8,10,14,16, etc\}$.  The set $\{0,\frac 16,\frac 23,\frac 12\}$ is not the same thing as the sequence which lists the set in some order with repetition.

Comment: The set of Fibonacci numbers is $\{1,2,3,5,8....\}$.  $1$ is not in the set twice.

Comment: The "set of terms of the Fibonacci sequence is the set $\{1,2,3,5,8,13,etc\}$ there are many many bijections to it.  But the one function we use to list them $f_1 = 1; f_2 = 1; f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$ does not happen to be a bijection.  So what?  There are others that are.  Example $g(1) =1; g(2) =2; g(3)=3; g(4)=5.... g(n) = f_{n+1}$ is a bijection.

Comment: "But no matter the function, we will have 2 distinct elements in the domain (Z+) mapping to the element, 1, in the co-domain."  Not at all true.   Why do you think that?  Just because $1$ is listed twice in the sequence does not mean it must be mapped to twice in  a function.  The *set* of fibonnaci is not the same thing as the sequence and just because a sequence may list terms multiple times, the only exist in the set once.

Comment: Sorry, @fleablood, I did not receive notifications about your comments so was unaware. I think I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

As a sequence is a set indexed by the natural numbers, there exists a surjection from the naturals to the set. Let $A$ be the set and g: $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$ the surjection. Then we can define a map $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as $f(a)=$ the minimum natural number n such that $g(n)=a$. Then f is injective and thus A must be countably infinite or finite. Further, you can similarly show that every set indexed by a countably infinite set is either finite or countably infinite.