# What is the cardinality of $\Bbb Q ^4$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of $\Bbb Q ^4$?

I understand that $\vert \Bbb Q \vert=\aleph _0$, and $\vert \Bbb Q ^4 \vert$ supposed to be $\aleph _0$, is there any formal proof to this?

Comment: Look here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable.

Comment: Before tackling $\mathbb Q^4$, do you know the cardinality of $\mathbb Q^2$?

Comment: Basically, you just need to show that $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. You can check the post [The cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54158) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/54158).

Answer (score 0):

Well, suppose the set $A$ is denumerable, i.e., $A=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$.
Then the set $A^2$ is denumerable. This can be shown by writing the elements of $A^2$ as an infinite matrix
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
(a_0,a_0) & (a_0,a_1) & (a_0,a_2) & \ldots\\
(a_1,a_0) & (a_1,a_1) & (a_1,a_2) & \ldots\\
(a_2,a_0) & (a_2,a_1) & (a_2,a_2) & \ldots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
\end{array}$$
These elements can be enumerated by walking through the array in zig-zag just as in Cantor's first diagonalization procedure. 
Now $A^2$ is denumerable and so $A^4=(A^2)^2$ is denumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Just in the same way you can prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable (Cantor's diagonal argument), you can also prove $\mathbb{N}^2$. Now. If $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}^2|$, $|\mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{N}^2 \times \mathbb{N}^2| = |\mathbb{N}^4| = |\mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N}|$

But $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Q}|$, therefore $|\mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{Q} \times  \mathbb{Q} \times  \mathbb{Q} \times  \mathbb{Q}|$